# ANDROID-JAVA - HTML Parsing - Hidden Input

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

i'm tryin to parse a document that have this code:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post" name="loginform" id="loginform" >
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='HCWAVsXHRc40Giq5gBZm0MtklzbTqic1' />

    <p>
        <label for="username">Nome utente<br />
        <input type="text"
                name="username"
                id="username"
                class="inputFields"
                value=""
                size="20"
                tabindex="1" />
        </label>
    </p>
    [...]
</form>
```

And i need to extract from here the csrfmiddlewaretoken, i am using jsoup but i am not able to get it...

Sorry for my english, i hope that you  understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at css selectors. A good starting point would be [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

I tried this simple one one here:
http://try.jsoup.org/~GT7K5vyOdnu16ShL7STeB-FdD1o
Using this selector:

> input[type="hidden"] or input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]

With this information following the Jsoup api you should be able to call

```
attr(String key)
```

on the retrieved element.

Comment: idk, i don't gave you a -1